# Question about the annotation box in mpldatacursor in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, mplcursors

According to the mpldatacursor 0.7.1 [project description](https://pypi.org/project/mpldatacursor/), it says that "mpldatacursor provides interactive “data cursors” (clickable annotation boxes) for matplotlib."

And I use the code in the project description, but I just get the image. When I click on the image, it doesn't show the annotation box.

My Python version is 3.8 and Pycharm version is professional 2019.2. By the way, there is no error when I run the code.

Does anyone know why?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpldatacursor import datacursor

data = np.arange(100).reshape((10,10))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
axes[0].imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower')
axes[1].imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', origin='upper',
                     extent=[200, 300, 400, 500])
datacursor(display='single')

fig.suptitle('Click anywhere on the image')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They've updated the code and it works now.

They removed `from mpldatacursor import datacursor` and replaced it with `import mplcursors`. You may need to install `mplcursors`

Updated code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mplcursors

data = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
axes[0].imshow(data, interpolation="nearest", origin="lower")
axes[1].imshow(data, interpolation="nearest", origin="upper",
                 extent=[200, 300, 400, 500])
mplcursors.cursor()

fig.suptitle("Click anywhere on the image")

plt.show()
```